# Rails association has_one one side and has_many another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models
 Group 
 Location

each group can have one location and each location can have many groups.

Is it possible to use

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :location 
end
```

and

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group 
end
```

What is the best way to define this association.

Can i use through association also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :location 
end
```

should be

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :location 
end
```

Comment: I can't create multiple groups on one location with it

Comment: you can refer this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association